# Middleware to Vuex state not updating state?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am trying to get my firestore data that I am getting to be stored in my state but it does not show up in my Vue dev tools in the state.

When I console.log() the data I am getting through the store action I can see I am getting the right data but it will not update the state.

I am using middle-ware on my home page and another page to dispatch my action in order to get the required data.

I have also used a conditional statement within the middle-ware below to try to only dispatch action when my other state variables are not null because the firestore query requires state.user

```
//this is check-auth middleware
 export default function(context) {
 // in initAuth we are forwarding it the req
  context.store.dispatch('initAuth', context.req)
  console.log('WE ARE GRABBING USER INFO')
  context.store.dispatch('grabUserInfo', context.req)
  console.log('There is already user info there')
  // context.store.dispatch('currentUser')
   }
```

We are  dispatching grabUserInfo to run a action that has a firestore query in it.

```
  grabUserInfo(vuexContext, context) {
     let userInfo = []
     var userRef = db.collection('users')
      var query = userRef
        .where('user_id', '==', vuexContext.state.user)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data())
          userInfo.push(doc.data())
          })
        })
      vuexContext.commit('setUserInfoSub', userInfo)
    }
```

my

```
   console.log(doc.data()) is showing
```

subscribers: ["noFace2"]
subscriptions: ["noFace3"]
user_id: "VbomJvANYDNe3Bek0suySs1L8oy1"
username: "noFace1"

my info should be going through a mutation and commiting to state, but it does not show up in my state vue dev tools.

```
 setUserInfoSub(state, payload) {
    state.userInfoSub = payload
  }
```

I don't understand how the data is not ending up in my state. Here is my State and mutations.

```
  const createStore = () => {
   return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
     loadedCards: [],
     user: null,
     username: null,
     userInfoSub: [],
     token: null
   },
    mutations: {
    setCards(state, cards) {
    state.loadedCards = cards
    },
    setUser(state, payload) {
    state.user = payload
    },
     setUsername(state, payload) {
     state.username = payload
    },
    setUserInfoSub(state, payload) {
    state.userInfoSub = payload
    },
    setToken(state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
```

Comment: You cannot directly change state from an action, you need a mutation. Use the action to committ a mutation, which will then update the state. The mutation would take `state` and your user data as a `payload` for the two parameters returned from the action. Vuex docs show this very well.

Comment: I have my mutation code right there in the question.... it’s the setUserInfoSub and at th bottom of the long code piece I commit this mutation

Comment: Can you post the structure of your state?

Comment: okay that is my state and mutations and my action is the 2nd piece of code

Comment: Nice, so I think the problem is you're trying to swap out array objects, instead of pushing info into the array that is already in state. Did you check the typeof(payload) before trying to set the state variable to it? That would be the first thing to do, to make sure it is indeed an array. Either way, I think it would be better to push the info object into the state array, rather than writing over the state variable.

Comment: Isn't `vuexContext.commit('setUserInfoSub', userInfo)` being executed outside of async `.get().then()`? So it would would `commit()` prior to the value from the Firebase query resolving? Effectively sending stale/undefined data to the mutation? At minimum it needs to be moved inside `.then()`.

Comment: try:
`Vue.set(state, 'userInfoSub', payload);` in the mutation

Comment: Thank you both for your answers @AlexanderStaroselsky was also correct with me having to move my commit into .then(), I included both answers in my code and it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mutation to this:

```
 setUserInfoSub(state, payload) {
    Vue.set(state, 'userInfoSub', payload);
    }
```

This will allow Vue's reactivity system to kick back in for the state variable reassignment.

Per @Alexander's comment, you should also move the `commit()` inside `then()` given the async nature of the Firebase query.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: You should update this answer to also include the key part of moving the `commit()` inside `then()` given the async nature of the Firebase query.

Comment: Added that detail

Comment: Hi @LenJoseph I get Vue is not defined when I change my mutation to Vue.set()... importing Vue from 'vue' doesn't worked either